# How to add double quotation in each index of json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

For connecting (sending data) to a SMS API service I need to convert my data to something that site can understand.(their API can't receive standard jsons)

For example I have an object like this :

```
var data = {
    message: ['hi', 'hello'],
    receptor: ['12345678', '87654321'],
    sender: ['1000' , '2000']
}
```

I need to convert it to something like this :

```
{
    message: "['hi', 'hello']",
    receptor: "['12345678', '87654321']",
    sender: "['1000' , '2000']"
}
```

I write a simple code to convert it :

```
for( var index in data ){
    new_data[index] =  "["+ data[index]  ;
    for( var j in data[index] ){
        new_data[index][j] = '"' + data[index][j] + '"';
    }
    new_data[index] += "]";
}
```

But single quotations inside arrays removed and return this :

```
{
    message: "[hi, hello]",
    receptor: "[12345678, 87654321]",
    sender: "[1000 , 2000]"
}
```

How can I do this?

I know that converting them to string and work with that can solve the problem, but I hope I can find a better way.

Comment: So you're looking to convert the arrays to string form and remove the quotations around the property names?

Comment: NO ,I want to find a better way.

Comment: I think you'd probably have to write your own function to do this, it seems like a really specific (and weird) format requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
    message: ['hi', 'hello'],
    receptor: ['12345678', '87654321'],
    sender: ['1000' , '2000']
}

for(key in data){
    data[key] = '[\'' + data[key].join("','") + '\']';
}
//output
{
message: "['hi','hello']", 
receptor: "['12345678','87654321']", 
sender: "['1000','2000']"
}
```

---

```
for(key in data){
    data[key] = '"[\'' + data[key].join("','") + '\']"';
}
//output
{
message: ""['hi','hello']"", 
receptor: ""['12345678','87654321']"", 
sender: ""['1000','2000']""
}
```

---

```
for(key in data){
    data[key] = JSON.stringify(data[key]);
}
//output
{
message: "["hi","hello"]", 
receptor: "["12345678","87654321"]", 
sender: "["1000","2000"]"
}
```

Comment: first code output is something like this : `message: '[\'hi\',\'hi\']'`

Answer (score -1):

var new_data = JSON.parse(data);
would print out what you requested as well

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I think you might have misunderstood the OP's question. The OP has a JavaScript object which needs to be converted into some stringified form. `JSON.stringify` would be closer to what the OP is looking for, but it appears that the OP is looking for something that isn't quite JSON.

Comment: right i wasn't paying attention sorry. Thanks for the welcome tho.